# JSP Cannot get value from input

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

EDIT: WORKS NOW! THANKS! So anchor is not a submit.

how come I cannot get the value of 'opr' from an input using doGet/doPost? I'm getting some nulls.

Form:

```
<form method="post" role="form" name="frm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Title" id="newsboxTitle" name="title">
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="newsbox" name="content"></textarea>

    <input type="hidden" name="page_action">
    <div>
        <a href="addNews" type="button" name="opr" class="btn btn-danger" value="1">Submit</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Servlet(newsUpdate.java):

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException{
    String opr = req.getParameter("title");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, opr);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/news.jsp").forward(req, res);
}

   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException{
    String opr = req.getParameter("title");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, opr);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/admin/news.jsp").forward(req, res);
}
```

also if I don't put doGet i get error 405.

here's my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addNews</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>processes.newsUpdates</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addNews</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/addNews</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Clicking an anchor and submitting a form are two different things.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Your comment is the answer. Consider moving it to an answer.

Comment: how do i tag this as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Clicking an anchor and submitting a form are two different things. – Sotirios Delimanolis

Until that comment becomes an answer, here we go...

This also explains the 405 error. Clicking on a link performs a "get" request. Therefore `doGet` is called, not `doPost`. This form needs a "submit" button or a JavaScript callback which submits the form to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the code use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, opr);`?  Get the value like any other parameter.  The code shouldn't be mixing Java Swing in a servlet, the user will never see it.

```
req.getParameter("opr")
```

Also the form should use a button to submit:

```
<button type="submit" name="opr" class="btn btn-danger" value="1">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I used JOptionPane to check whether I got the value from String opr = req.getParameter("title");